# How do I select elements on a <canvas> element?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate [ticket reservation on the redBus site](https://www.redbus.in/search?fromCityName=Chennai&fromCityId=123&toCityName=Bangalore&toCityId=122&onward=21-Apr-2017&opId=0&busType=Any) using Java and Selenium WebDriver.

Seats can be reserved by clicking on them in a picture:

[image: Seat arrangements]

It is a `canvas` element, so the seats to click aren't separate DOM elements.
How can I still automate selecting a seat?

Comment: Please ask a question.

Comment: I need to automate the seat selection procedure. How do I start? I'm new to selenium automation

Comment: I have rewritten it to ask what I think is your question. Please fix if necessary.  You must ask a very specific question, or else the question will be rejected as overly broad.

Comment: Thanks @reinierost . I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @AkashPrabhakaran did you find a solution for this